# Having trouble in creating forms in django

Tags: django, django-forms

This is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Article(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog,
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    body = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is my forms.py file

```
from blog.models import Article
from django import forms
        
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'draft']
```

Here is the views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from blog.forms import ArticleForm

# Create your views here.


def add_article(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Article created")
        else:
            context = {'form': ArticleForm()}
            return render(request, 'add_article.html', context)
    context = {'form': ArticleForm()}
    return render(request, 'add_article.html', context)
```

Can someone tell me how do I insert the first attribute of class Article which is blog in class Articleform?

I am learning django and some help will be appreciated.

Comment: Share the view where you use this form.

Comment: The view (and url) should take as parameter the primary key/slug/something else that uniquely determines the `Blog` object.

Comment: if you want to include **blog** in `ArticleForm`, then add it inside fields, which is `fields = ['blog', 'title', 'body', 'draft']`

Comment: @AdilMohak: I don't think it should be included in the form. Likely it is more like adding an `Article` to an already existing `Blog`, and you thus link to it. For example like a comment on an existing post.

Answer (score 0):

You can check these steps:

> be sure you added `{{form}}` in your **add_article.html**.
>
> be sure you added `method="POST"` in your `<form>` tag.

e.g.:

```
<form method="POST">
{{form}}
<input type="submit">Post</input>
</form>
```